# How to make changes to third party package in React Native 0.60+

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-camera

I'm struggling with making changes and possible a pull request for a third party react native package with cocoapods and auto linking.

In this case I want to add some minor functionality to React Native Camera. And I've forked the repo.

While developing I'd like to use my local code, but I can't get it to work.

I'ven tried using npm link, but this doesn't work since React Native can't find the linked package with the TypeScript import statement.

I've also tried just to edit Objective C code directly in node_modules, running pod install again and rerunning react-native run-ios, but it doesn't seem to include my changes.

I've never really made pull requests to other packages before, so I think I need some help. I thought this would be the easiest thing to google, but it turns out it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You may be doing this already, but make sure that you clean and rebuild the project from xcode if you're modifying objective C code in the node modules folder, before re running react-native run-ios.

If you've already installed the library you also shouldn't need to rerun pod install.

Similarly on android, be sure to rebuild the project in android studio.